# .Net Regex - last of repeating characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to capture everything inside curly bracers, but in some cases there may be multiple bracers and I want the external ones.

For example: I want to capture `{{this}}` part
I'll need `{{this}}` as the capture.

So I went with `({[^}]+}+)` to capture the inner text, but of course this will yield multiple captures `{{this}` and `{{this}}`.

So I tried telling the regex to search for the phrase but only if the next character is not curly bracers: `({[^}]+}+)[^}]`. This works, unless the capture is at the end of the input, in which case it doesn't work cause it expects a non `}` character at the end.

So I tried adding end of string option `({[^}]+}+)[$|^}]`, but for some reason, this will capture `{{this}` again. I have no idea why, it should only capture if the next char is end of input or not curly bracers...

Suggestions?

Edit:

Just to be clear, I'm not searching for valid nested parenthesis, only for text between { and the first matching } (no nesting!), however there may be cases where instead of one open/close brace there are two (so {something} and {{something}} both need to be caught).

The reason for this, is that the original text always has double braces {{ }}, but sometimes before the regex the text undergoes string.Format, in which case the double braces become single braces.

Comment: Do you want to capture the 2nd {{this}} and not the 1st? If so, is this what you want https://regex101.com/r/eT5hB9/1 ?

Comment: If the string has `{text}}`, do you want to capture all but the last brace? Or nothing?

Comment: everything between the first opening brace, and the first consecutive closing brace, including the braces themselves. Edited the question to explain better.

Comment: So do you need to match all `{{{this}}}` but capture `{{{this}}}`, `{{this}}` and `{this}`?

Comment: I need to match and capture {{{{{{this}}}}}, when there are consecutive bracers I want them all matched and captured, the amount doesn't matter and it doesn't matter if every opening brace has a closing one.

Comment: c0d3man's answer is perfect since it took my own regex that did exactly what I needed, but fixed a syntax error that I was unaware of. (using | inside [])

Comment: This is the short version  `{+[^}]+}+` of your fixed regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have used a character class at the end instead of a non-capturing group. Try:

```
({[^}]+}+)(?:$|[^}])
```

This is a very small modification to your final attempt, that just uses correct syntax. In your final attempt you have `[$|^}]`. The issue with this is that you can't have an or `|` inside a character class `[]`. Most special characters are escaped inside a character class, with a couple exceptions, one of which is `^` if it is the first character. So `[$|^}]` means any of the four literal characters `$`, `|`, `^`, or `}`. What I did is change the syntax to what you intended by using a non-capturing group `(?:stuff)` this group does not save its contents and is purely for grouping. As such `(?:$|[^}])` means an end-of-line or a non-`}`, as you wanted.

Note that this makes no effort to balance the curly braces (match the number of braces at the beginning and end).

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Can you explain what you did here, I'm not familiar with these.

Comment: This solution will match as many `}`s at the end as you have, so if you provide `{{this}}}}` it will match all four curly braces at the end.

Comment: Yes I get that it works, but I don't understand why. Why does defining a non capturing group work, and outside of the group it doesn't work? what's the difference?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is correct - this makes no effort to match the number of braces at the beginning and end (and IIRC that's a theoretically impossible problem for rexeges if you don't know a maximum number of braces).

Comment: @tbkn23 this is a very small modification to your final attempt, that just uses correct syntax. In your final attempt you have `[$|^}]`. The issue with this is that you can't have an or (`|`) inside a character class (`[]`). Most special characters are escaped inside a character class, with a couple exceptions, one of which is `^` if it is the first character. So `[$|^}]` means any of the four literal characters `$`, `|`, `^`, or `}`. What I did is change the syntax to what you intended by using a non-matching group `(?:stuff)` this group does not save its contents and is purely for grouping.

Comment: Cont. As such `(?:$|[^}])` means an end-of-line or a non-`}`, as you wanted.

Comment: @c0d3man thank you for your solution and explanation to what I did wrong. I wasn't aware that [] behaves as you explained it, now it's clear.

Comment: @tbkn23, beware that this regex is also matching any character **after** the last closing brace. I think my answer is extremely simpler, doesn't have this issue and can easily be changed not to accept spaces or numbers.

Comment: "Non-matching group" is inaccurate and potentially confusing to regex beginners.   I corrected it to *non-capturing group*.

Comment: I don't see the point of that last part anyway.  If the text that's captured in group 1 is all you're interested in, then that's the only part of the regex you need.  [Andrew's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38908137/20938) matches just that, and is much more readable.

Comment: I agree that Andrew's answer was much simpler, I was just trying to give an answer that made sense to the OP - he seemed to have wanted to do this but messed up the syntax. I considered adding the simpler version to my answer but figure Andrew has that covered.

Comment: @Andrew it may be matching the character but it doesn't capture it, which is what the original regexes seemed to do.

Comment: @Alan Moore the last part us to make sure we capture the last closing braces in a row, and not the first, hence it is necessary.

Comment: @Andrew your answer is indeed simple but doesn't do what I need it to do. I need the text with the bracers, including all the bracers when there are multiple consecutive opening or closing bracers.

Comment: @tbkn23, and doesn't my regex do that? Please check my updated answer, I added a comment there because it wouldn't be readable here. I don't find the benefit of the other answers, besides the symmetry of dasblinkenlight's.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, regex is not powerful enough to do this. However, .NET regex engine supports so-called [*Atomic Grouping*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), which let you process groups with balanced parentheses:

```
{(?>{(?<DEPTH>)|}(?<-DEPTH>)|[^}]+)*}(?(DEPTH)(?!))
```

Comment: `there may be multiple bracers and I want the external ones` - I don't think he understands nesting or _balanced_. +1 For the right solution, but he probably doesn't understand it..

Comment: Complex but cool. You may want to use `[^}\\s]+` instead to avoid spaces (I guess they aren't valid).

Comment: Also, if he were looking for only adjacent (inner) `{{{` and `}}}` something like `{(?>(?<={){(?<DEPTH>)|}(?=})(?<-DEPTH>)|[^{}]+)*}(?(DEPTH)(?!))` would work.

Comment: This seems over complex. Isn't there a way to say "either this character or end of string"? So if I wanted a word ending with "ed", I'd want "ed" then any whitespace OR end of string. That can't be done in a simple way?

Comment: @tbkn23 There is no way to do it properly without atomic groups. Such expressions would be simpler, but they could be tricked into accepting a wrong sequence (e.g. `{this}}` would match the whole thing instead of `{this}`). Accepting balanced brackets is a hard problem, which .NET has addressed with this particular feature. Other regex engines cannot solve this problem at all.

Comment: actually that's exactly what I need, to match {this}} (the whole thing) not just the inner braces. I'm not looking for balanced bracers. See my edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match all text between braces, I think this should do the trick:

```
{+.*?}+
```

This matches everything between braces, taking all consecutive braces and as few internal characters as possible.

*Further explanation: matches 1 or more {* (`{+`)*, then any amount of any character* (`.*`) *but gives you the shortest string that does it* (`?`)*, and finally matches 1+ }* (`}+`)*. Without that `?`, if you have `{a} {b}` it would match the whole thing instead of `{a}` and `{b}` separately.*

If you won't want spaces between the braces, you can use this:

```
{+\S*?}+
```

If you only want letters, use `\w` instead of `\S`.

The only thing this is not validating is that the same amount of braces are used. Do you need that?

---

Result comparison (should be a comment).

Considering `{{{{{{this}}}}}Blabla`, I get this:

**Regex author: c0d3rman**

- Matched string: `{{{{{{this}}}}}B`
- Groups: 2 (`{{{{{{this}}}}}B` and `{{{{{{this}}}}}`)
- Captures: `{{{{{{this}}}}}`

**Regex author: dasblinkenlight**

- Matched string: `{{{{{this}}}}}`
- Groups: 2 (`{{{{{this}}}}}` and `{}`)
- Captures: `{{{{{this}}}}}`

Note: *symmetric braces*

**Regex author: Andrew**

- Matched string: `{{{{{{this}}}}}`
- Groups: `{{{{{{this}}}}}`
- Captures: `{{{{{{this}}}}}`

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't _capture_ anything. Add `()`.

Comment: It seems to work. Although it's missing the capture (since that was in the question), and also an explanation of how it works would be nice.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you need then. Do you need to **match** something **and also capture** part of what you matched? BTW, if you were able to create that regex in your question, I didn't think you would have any issue with my regex, which is extremely simple. I'll add the explanation anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's clear now. I wasn't familiar with the "shortest string" syntax.

Comment: But what option did you end up using? Did you notice the issue with the regex of your accepted answer?